# How do you solve $(A - \omega^2 B + i \omega C) x = 0$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

How do you solve $(A - \omega^2 B + i \omega C) x = 0$ where A and B are real symmetric positive-definite matrices, C might be real or complex (either would do to start with) and x is a vector that I guess is complex? $\omega$ and $x$ are the unknowns.

It looks a bit like the generalized eigenvalue problem $(A - \lambda B) x = 0$ so maybe it can be converted into that form?

I hope to get it in a form that can be solved using common linear algebra libraries.

Comment: Do you need to characterize all solutions in some sense or will you be okay with just one? If you just need to find one or a few solutions you can probably do a two step iterative numerical approach where one solves for x and the second solves for $\omega$. You will need a regularization term when solving for x so that you disqualify the trivial 0 vector as a solution.

Comment: I want the several (~1-100) lowest $\omega$ solutions. Your suggestion sounds like the same level of difficulty as making an eigenvalue solver which is beyond my capability. It needs to be robust, fast and work on a variety of large sparse matrices. It seems like a black art finding good convergence criteria, ways to update the variables at each iteration, and starting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is called a "quadratic eigenvalue problem" and can be converted to an ordinary one with bigger matrices like this:

$$
D \Psi = \lambda E \Psi
$$

where
$\lambda = i \omega$

$\Psi = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ \lambda x\end{bmatrix}$

$D = \begin{bmatrix}-A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}$

$E = \begin{bmatrix}C & B\\B & 0\end{bmatrix}$

This was done by including another equation

$\lambda Bx - \lambda Bx = 0 $ which gives the B terms to the bottom rows of the new matrices.

There are also other forms you can use listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_eigenvalue_problem#Methods_of_solution.